# Tridion General and Tridion Search Indexer Errors

Tags: core-service, 2011-sp1, search

Recently our Tridion 2011 has been updated to SP1.

In EventViewer we face with a lot of the same errors which occur several times in a minute.
First error belongs to "Tridion Search" and looks following:

`Nullable object must have a value.

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.Handling.DefaultSearchIndexingHandler.GetBinaryFileName(BinaryContentData binaryContentData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.Handling.DefaultSearchIndexingHandler.ExtractIndexFields(IdentifiableObjectData subjectData, Item item)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.SearchIndexingEngine.AddToIndex(TcmUri subjectId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchIndexer.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()`

And the second error belongs to "Tridion General" and looks following:

`The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:10:00'.
The write operation failed, see inner exception.
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:10:00'.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.FlushCore(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.WriteNow(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, BufferManager bufferManager)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartWriting(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeWriter.FlushBuffer()
   at System.Xml.XmlStreamNodeWriter.WriteBytes(Byte[] byteBuffer, Int32 byteOffset, Int32 byteCount)
   at System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeWriter.WriteBase64Text(Byte[] trailBytes, Int32 trailByteCount, Byte[] base64Buffer, Int32 base64Offset, Int32 base64Count)
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseWriter.WriteBase64(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter.WriteValue(IStreamProvider value)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncoderFactory.BinaryMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Stream stream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamingConnectionHelper.WriteMessage(Message message, IConnection connection, Boolean isRequest, IConnectionOrientedTransportFactorySettings settings, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonConnectionReader.StreamedFramingRequestContext.OnReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc& rpc)`

Can someone give an advice how to fix it?

Comment: Can you verify if the "Tridion Content Manager Search Host" is running on the machine? Can you next verify whether the default port 8983 is opened in the Windows firewall?

Comment: yes, service is running and localhost:8983 is open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but it seems that search indexer is failing to index (some) multimedia components. The reason might be that multimedia component is deleted by the time indexer gets to it, or there's something special about it. I would suggest you to:

- Clear the indexer queue. This will prevent future errors
- Create a new multimedia component, check if it will be indexed. If it will - you may start reindexing publication by publication until you will find which multimedia component is causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Unfortunately, I'm not aware how to clear the queue. Should I clear some table in db? Maybe there is some documentation about this or some article?

Comment: In 2011 SP1 you need to run Re-index tool. It's in the start menu, under Tridion folder

Comment: @AndreyMarchuk does the same re-index tool exist for 2013? Does this exist out in Tridion World ?